# The Bayesian Choice/evaluation/unknown pharse

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayes-theorem

[Here](http://www.calvin.edu/~stob/courses/Bayesian%20Computation/Robert%20Book.pdf) (Large file) on the page 53, in the example 2.1.2, I do not understand the phrase

$\delta$ stands for an evaluation of $\theta$.

What does this mean, esp. the word **evaluation**?

In the link above you'll find a nice book on Bayesian Statistics.

Comment: It is not totally clear, but the book seems to use *evaluation* to mean various things, including *calculation of a value* or *judging how good* a procedure is against a loss function or something close to *a particular value of an estimator* (i.e. an estimate).  My guess, in this particular example, it has a meaning close to the third

Comment: Do you mean the measured outcome out of an experiment after observing data,i.e.measuring the parameter $\theta$?

Comment: You typically do not measure a parameter, but observe something else, and then (in a Bayesian inference context) use that observation to refine your belief about the parameter

Comment: What is exactly the difference of refining (2nd part of your sentence) my belief of the parameter from measuring it (1st part of your sentence) ? What do you mean by "else" ?

Comment: For example if I have unknown parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for a Beta distribution, I do not measure them when I observe values but I can draw inferences about them

Comment: You might post this question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). The [author](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7224/xian) of the book is an active user of that site. If you do that, do link to this post here.